# How to write Test case for NFT buy functionaity?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, remix-tests, chai

Function for buying NFT

```
function buy(address nftContract, uint256 itemId)
    public
    payable
    nonReentrant
{
    uint256 price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price;
    uint256 tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;
    require(
        msg.value >= price,
        "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase"
    );

    idToMarketItem[itemId].seller.transfer(msg.value);
    fandomToken(nftContract).transfer(msg.sender, tokenId, 1);
    idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
    idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = true;
    _itemsSold.increment();
   
}
```

Test case for the above code

```
describe('buy', async() => {
    it('buy functionality check ', async()=>{
        const nftContract = '0x8CdaF0CD259887258Bc13a92C0a6dA92698644C0'
        console.log("ACCOUNT 2",accounts[2])
        const result_nftContract = await contract_nFTMarket.buy(nftContract,1, {from: accounts[0],Value: 2000000000000000000})
        console.log("---->>>>",result_nftContract)
        const eventMinted = await result_nftContract.logs[0].args
        // assert.equal(eventMinted.category,'video')
        // assert.equal(eventMinted.nftContract,contract_address)
    })
})
```

but still, I am getting below error

**Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase -- Reason given: Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase.
**

Comment: Caculate and check the price before calling the buyFunction, your price is less than the 2ETH

Answer (score 0):

I think error is here:

```
{from: accounts[0],Value: 2000000000000000000})
```

`Value` is capital letter. should be `{value: 2000000000000000000})`